# JDK error while i run react-native-doctor but i already upgrade jdk version

Tags: java, android, react-native

So i have error while i run react-native-doctor

```
✖ JDK
   - Version found: 1.8.0_352
   - Version supported: >= 8
 ✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✓ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME
```

can anyone solve that problem?

Comment: you need to change your JDK from 1.8 to 8 or higher, I refer to using JDK 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install it with brew

```
brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
brew install --cask zulu11
```

Then check in terminal

```
java -version
openjdk version "11.0.13" 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.13+8 (build 11.0.13+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.13+8 (build 11.0.13+8, mixed mode)
```